# Submit movie showtimes in Google movies

Tags: google-search, microdata, movies

I've created a movie theater website and now I would like to submit movie's showtimes to Google Movies. How can I do that?
My website has microdata's structure and a page on Google Places, but I don't know how to include movies information in Google Movies.
I know there are other questions regarding this topic (like this [How to include movie showtimes in Google Movies?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2494698/how-to-include-movie-showtimes-in-google-movies)), but they are very old and none of them gave me a useful answer.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and after trying everything we could find we eventually had to bite the bullet and pay West World Media to get listed in Google. Ideally there wouldn't be a company you have to pay to get this done, but that's probably a conversation for another forum.

We sent cinema source our listings for months with no results. You can get listed in Gracenote publications and Fandango for free though by emailing times@nowshowing.com and listings@fandango.com respectively.

Comment: Ok, I am a cinema owner in Australia and am looking deep into this very secretive issue.  I will try and make any info I find public.  I was attempting to write a Wordpress plug that would create schema.org output suitable to google but they ignore it.  I am trying to find out why.

Answer (score -1):

Send your movie showtimes to schedules@cinema-source.com. They input all of the showtimes manually so any schedule you can send will be great.

I heard that Google uses this company for its showtimes. http://www.westworldmedia.com/movies.asp

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I sent my showtimes but I didn't have any reply. Are there any other services for submitting?